# Delay Mirth message delivery

Tags: windows, mirth

I am interfacing with a system which schedules appointments.  The destination system does not allow appointments to be scheduled more than 30 days in advance, but the source system may send the appointment at any time (frequently beyond 30 days).  How can I delay the delivery of the message till it is within the 30d window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create two channels.  Have the first write the file to disk and set the "lastWriteTime" to the date you would like the message to be delivered.  The second channel should read from this directory and use the "Check File Time" option to filter only those messages with historical dates.

#### Channel 1 destination 1:

##### Transformer Javascript:

```js
    channelMap.put('deliverAfter', msg['SCH']['SCH.11']['SCH.11.1'].toString());
```

##### Destination Settings:

Connector Type: Javascript Writer

```js
    var deliverAfter = DateUtil.getDate('yyyyMMddHHmm', $('deliverAfter'));
    var path = 'c:/data/queue/' + connectorMessage.getMessageId();
    org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new java.io.File(path), connectorMessage.getEncodedData(), 'UTF-8');
    java.nio.file.Files.setLastModifiedTime(java.nio.file.Paths.get(path), java.nio.file.attribute.FileTime.fromMillis(deliverAfter.getTime()));
```

#### Channel 2:

##### Source reader settings:

Path: `c:/data/queue/`
After Processing Action: Delete
Check File Age: Yes
File age (ms): 1000
Encoding: UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

To avoid queuing messages to meet the delay threshold expected at the destination, I would do a JavaScript filter on the source connector of the source system to only fetch appointments that the destination considers due. For further assistance, you can share a template of a source system message sample (arbitrary values not real data, I am only interested in the place holders).

Comment: Source Filters execute after the reader is completed.  Unless the reader has a method of filtering pre-read (e.g. DB Reader), I don't see how this would work.  How would the message be later delivered once the delay has finished?

Comment: The original post did not hint that the source system is using a Javascript reader. Perhaps you share further details regarding the configuration set up, specifically how the source and destination connectors in the two end points are configured. That will help address the second concern too.

Comment: I do not specify the type of source reader, since I am looking for a solution that works with any source reader.  Can you edit your answer to include an example of what you are suggesting?  I don't see how a delay could be made in the source filter.